# Convert Combobox percent to double variable

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, vba, visual-studio-2012

I am using VB.Net to create an amortization calculator using visual studio 2012. I have a combo box that contains a list of percentages:

```
Dim dblInterest As Double

    Dim InterestRateInput

    For InterestRateInput = 20 To 2000 Step 1
        dblInterest = Math.Round(InterestRateInput / 10000, 4)

        cboInterestRateInput.Items.Add(FormatPercent(dblInterest))
```

Since I formatted the value to a percent I can no longer convert it to a double because it has the "%" sign in it. How would I convert the percentages to a double after the user selects the desired percent? I am trying to execute this line of code without success:

```
dblAnnualRate = CDbl(cboInterestRateInput.Items(cboInterestRateInput.SelectedIndex))
```

EDIT: To resolve this issue I did dblAnnualRate = CDbl(cboInterestRateInput.Items(cboInterestRateInput.SelectedIndex).ToString.Rep‌​lace("%", "")) Added another variable which I set equal to dblAnnualRate /100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String.Replace("%","")` to replace the "%" and then `Double.TryParse()` to convert the string to double

Comment: I did dblAnnualRate = CDbl(cboInterestRateInput.Items(cboInterestRateInput.SelectedIndex).ToString.Replace("%", ""))

Added another variable which I set equal to dblAnnualRate /100 
It works! Thank You!